# Chaining functions in jquery so that one starts after another has finis

Tags: jquery, json

I have two functions, functionA() and functionB(), each of which contain a $.getJSON.  And, depending on what data is returned from functionA(), functionB() will behave differently. I had been using:

```
functionA();
functionB();
```

However, with this setup, I was sometimes getting some unexpected results from functionB().  My thinking was that functionB()'s JSON call was starting even though functionA()'s JSON call had not been completed.  My solution to this was to put functionB() inside of $.getJSON's ".done".  And while this works, I was wondering if there's a more elegant way of chaining functionA() and functionB() so that functionB() doesn't start until functionA() has entirely completed and at the same time, my functionB() call is outside of functionA().

Comment: Would you mind passing in `functionB` as a parameter to `functionA`?\

Comment: I've never passed a function as a parameter.  Could you please clarify how this would work?  (And if it's anything like passing a variable, I wouldn't mind at all!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using the `callback` syntax (well known from `node.js` for example):

```
functionA(functionB);
```

While your functions take a `callback` argument:

```
functionA(callback){
  // do stuff

  // when ready, run:
  return callback();
};
```

---

If your calls are getting more complex, you might want to take a look at the library <kbd>**[async](https://github.com/caolan/async)**</kbd>

Comment: @Eric -- This is what I mean't :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of achieving this. You obviously need to wait for functionA()'s JSON call to finish before functionB() gets executed. One method of doing this would be to call functionB() from inside the success() handler in functionA()'s JSON call, for example:

```
function functionA() {
    $.getJSON(url, data, function(result) {
        // do something
        functionB();
    });
}

function functionB() {
    // do something
}

functionA();
```

If you do not want to hardcode functionB inside functionA, you can also pass it as an argument and call it that way, for example:

```
function functionA(callback) {
    $.getJSON(url, data, function(result) {
        // do something
        callback();
    });
}

function functionB() {
    // do something
}

functionA(functionB);
```

Another, more elegant and scalable solution is to let functionA()'s JSON call trigger a custom event when it's done, and create a new event handler for that particular event which then triggers functionB. This way functionA and functionB remain completely decoupled, do not need to know each other, but you can still ensure the proper order of execution. 
You can read about triggering and catching custom events here: [JQuery.trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: RienNeVaPlus beat you to the punch.  However, I appreciate your very detailed answer.  In addition, though the callback syntax works for my current needs, I'll investigate triggering and catching custom events as well.

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON` is an asynchronous call, so you must call `functionB()` in your callback for `functionA()`'s $.getJSON unless you use a synchronous AJAX request.  
To use a synchrounous request, you need to set the `async` variable to false using a custom `$.ajax` request instead of a $.getjson.  See [jQuery.ajax() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Ajax/jQuery.ajax&redirect=no) on the ajax options. [jQuery.getJSon() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) show an example on how to configure ajax for json.